# Task config is invalid: Input task is invalid

Tags: openstack, rally, cinder

now i have a problem with openstack banch mark with rally.

i want to benchmark my cinder system. and i install
openstack (Queens) / rally (0.11.0) and i already test openstack and rally is working properly.

and i try bench mark with this scenario

```
{
"CinderVolumes.create_and_attach_volume": [
    {
        "args": {
            "size": 10,
            "image": {
                "name": "cirros"
            },
            "flavor": {
                "name": "m1.tiny"
            },
            "create_volume_params": {
                "availability_zone": "nova"
            }
        },
        "runner": {
            "type": "constant",
            "times": 5,
            "concurrency": 1
        },
        "context": {
            "users": {
                "tenants": 2,
                "users_per_tenant": 2
            },
            "api_versions": {
                "cinder": {
                   "version": 2,
                   "service_type": "volumev2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

but, with this scenario. rally return error like this

> Task config is invalid: `Input task is invalid!
>
> Subtask CinderVolumes.create_and_attach_volume[0] has wrong
>   configuration Subtask configuration: {"version": 2, "title": "A
>   cropped version of a bigger task.", "description": "Auto-generated
>   task from a single workload", "subtasks": [{"title":
>   "CinderVolumes.create_and_attach_volume", "description": "Create a VM
>   and attach a volume to it.", "scenario":
>   {"CinderVolumes.create_and_attach_volume": {"size": 10, "image":
>   {"name": "cirros"}, "flavor": {"name": "m1.tiny"},
>   "create_volume_params": {"availability_zone": "nova"}}}, "contexts":
>   {"users": {"tenants": 2, "users_per_tenant": 2}, "api_versions":
>   {"cinder": {"version": 2, "service_type": "volumev2"}}}, "runner":
>   {"constant": {"times": 5, "concurrency": 1}}, "hooks": [], "sla":
>   {"failure_rate": {"max": 0}}}]}
>
> Reason(s):  'cinder' service is not available. Hint: If 'cinder'
>   service has non-default service_type, try to setup it via
>   'api_versions' context.

`

how can i solve this problem? And I'll give you some more information on this.

```
[root@controller ~]# rally deployment check
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Platform openstack:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Available services:
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| Service     | Service Type | Status    |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| __unknown__ | placement    | Available |
| __unknown__ | volumev2     | Available |
| __unknown__ | volumev3     | Available |
| glance      | image        | Available |
| keystone    | identity     | Available |
| neutron     | network      | Available |
| nova        | compute      | Available |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+


[root@controller ~]# openstack catalog list
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name      | Type      | Endpoints                                                              |
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| keystone  | identity  | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   admin: http://controller:5000/v3/                                    |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   public: http://controller:5000/v3/                                   |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   internal: http://controller:5000/v3/                                 |
|           |           |                                                                        |
| cinderv2  | volumev2  | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   internal: http://controller:8776/v2/7dd48a8542444579bcec3fe4b638069e |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   public: http://controller:8776/v2/7dd48a8542444579bcec3fe4b638069e   |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   admin: http://controller:8776/v2/7dd48a8542444579bcec3fe4b638069e    |
|           |           |                                                                        |
| nova      | compute   | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   admin: http://controller:8774/v2.1                                   |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   public: http://controller:8774/v2.1                                  |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   internal: http://controller:8774/v2.1                                |
|           |           |                                                                        |
| cinderv3  | volumev3  | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   public: http://controller:8776/v3/7dd48a8542444579bcec3fe4b638069e   |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   internal: http://controller:8776/v3/7dd48a8542444579bcec3fe4b638069e |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   admin: http://controller:8776/v3/7dd48a8542444579bcec3fe4b638069e    |
|           |           |                                                                        |
| glance    | image     | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   internal: http://controller:9292                                     |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   public: http://controller:9292                                       |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   admin: http://controller:9292                                        |
|           |           |                                                                        |
| placement | placement | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   internal: http://controller:8778                                     |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   public: http://controller:8778                                       |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   admin: http://controller:8778                                        |
|           |           |                                                                        |
| neutron   | network   | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   internal: http://controller:9696                                     |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   admin: http://controller:9696                                        |
|           |           | RegionOne                                                              |
|           |           |   public: http://controller:9696                                       |
|           |           |                                                                        |
+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is a bit late, but for future search requests...It is not full info about your Rally deployment, but:

```
            "api_versions": {
            "cinder": {
               "version": 2,
               "service_type": "volumev2"
            }
        }
```

This part and scenario is good, but you need to recheck that `api_versions` part. Check what you have as an output for `rally deployment check`. And then use `rally plugin show api_versions` as an example to correct your scenario. Also I believe that v2 for Cinder is deprecated and doesn't work. Use v3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a corresponding rally [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/rally/+bug/1785072)

Comment: it is better to explain the answer instead pf putting a link